# Having the same "au FilterWritePost" in vimrc and gvimrc - are both called in vim?

Tags: vim

If I have `au FilterWritePost * do_something` in `.vimrc` and `au FilterWritePost * do_something2` in `.gvimrc` and open gVim and do this event, are both called, or does the `.gvimrc` definition "overrides" the .vimrc definition (do_something2 only instead of do_something, or both)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to jackerran answer: use autocommand groups:

```
" Name may be any, but it should not be equal to any of events name. "
" Case is ignored "
augroup ThisDoesSomething
    " Wipe out every event from this group "
    autocmd!
    autocmd! FilterWritePost * do_something
augroup END
```

This is safe to be put both into vimrc and gvimrc at one time: `au!` will clear duplicates if they occur.

Comment: This is a better way of accomplishing it. It is always a good idea to get in the habit of grouping your autocommands.

Answer (score 4):

Yes they will. You can prevent this from happening by typing it this way

`au! FilterWritePost * do_something2`

the ! tells the autocommand to replace any other autocommand with the same FilterWritePost signature. If you fire up gvim the .vimrc will fire off first then the .gvimrc so your autocommand in the .vimrc will be replaced with the version in your .gvimrc

Comment: +1, thanks for you both explanations, indeed augroups as pointed out by @ZyX are really interesting. Thanks for helping out!